# Edit the header tag in SFMC Content Builder template

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, header

I am trying to edit the  tag in a template I've built in content builder but it's all locked down.
I need to add a tracking tax for a software we use in the header and also I wanted to call in a font hosted on our website that I need to call from the head tag.
Is there a way to unlock this?  I do not want to move to HTML paste, I want to build a template that others in the company can drag and drop into but I have to be able to get to this.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some more info on what you have tried? E.g. Where are you looking that you are finding it locked? Is it in the email or in the template?

Comment: The template. For example:
Content Builder>Create Button>Email>Create Method:Template>Blank Page>Select>enter name, description, etc>next>Code view tab.
Here is where I'd like to edit that head tag but there is a little lock icon there and I can't type anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After poking around with Content builder, I realized that what I needed to do instead was create a template, not an email.
By Clicking Content Builder>Create>Template>From Existing Template>Empty Tab>Blank Page>Select
I was able to edit the head tag however I want to.

Then, build the email with Create>Email>Template>Saved Tab>The tempalte I just made> drag in my content blocks and there you have it...